# multi tenancy and rspec

Tags: rspec, factory-bot, multi-tenant

I'm still getting familiar w/ RSpec and am running into some issue when setting up test for my multi tenant app.

The app works at:

client1.example.com

client2.example.com

etc....

In my RSpec i'm doing the following:

```
let(:tenant) { FactoryGirl.create(:tenant, subdomain: "client1") }
let(:root_path) { "http://client1.example.dev:3000" }

before {
  tenant.save
  visit root_path
}

describe "header" do
   it "should have the right title" do
     page.should have_selector('title', :text => tenant.name)
   end
end
```

I'm doing a few things that feel wrong here, but not sure what the best approach is.

1. I'm hard coding the root_path.  Doing something like `visit '/'` doesn't work as the Test doesn't know what the correct subdomain is.  Is this OK?
2. I'm not sure why, but I am having to do tenant.save before each test in order for the test to actually be able to find the tenant based on the subdomain.  If I remove tenant.save I get a `Couldn't find Tenant with subdomain = client1` error.  I thought FactoryGirl.create actually saved to the database?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Seems like this would be necessary, I don't think there is a way to specify only the subdomain.

2: Yes, `create` saves to the database (while `build` does not). However, RSpec's `let` is lazy - it only evaluates when it is first called.

That means without the `tenant.save` the tenant wouldn't be created until `page.should have_selector('title', :text => tenant.name)` happened - after the `visit` call, so too late.

Fortunately, RSpec also provides `let!` which is an eager version of `let`, so if you use that you won't need the `tenant.save` in the `before` block.